# Is there possible to specific type of Generic Type in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm student and I wonder there're a way to specific a type for Generic type?
Example, I has a `IEntity` interface as the code below

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T : // What I should input here?
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

If I only want T is `int`, `string`, and `Guid`, what should I do?
I tried do this:

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T : int, string, Guid // Compile Error: 
//'int' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
//'string' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
//'Guid' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

I can make T as `IComparable` for `int`, `string` and `Guid`, but some data type such as float also be delivered from `IComparable` too. I just want 3 type: `int`, `string` and `Guid`, is there able to do that?

Comment: Not possible yet.

Comment: related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: @OlivierRogier You say "yet", I would suggest "ever"

Comment: @DavidG Discriminated Unions are on the cards for C# 9, which would cover this use-case.

Comment: @DavidG It would be great to be able to do that. As having the diamond operator to do true generic polymorphism on open types.

Comment: One way would be to check `typeof(T)` in the constructor against a whitelist, and throw if it's not on there. But I'm fairly sure plenty of duplicates exist explaining how to do so.

Comment: @canton7 I'd be very surprised to see DUs make it into C# 9, we don't even have record types yet which I suspect would be a prerequisite.

Comment: I hope C# 9 can be some feature to do this

Comment: @DavidG There are hints in some of the LDM minutes, and in issues opened against coreclr. They're also championed, against the "9.0 candidate" milestone. It looks like they are being considered alongside records.

Comment: @canton7 Record types were championed against C# 6...

Comment: @DavidG Sure. I said they were on the cards for C# 9, not that they'll definitely get implemented then. A man can dream!